# Android Gradle: API dependency not exposed to client

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have the following situation:
Project A contains two library modules `libA` and `libExtension`. libA uses

```
dependencies {
api project(':libExtension')
}
```

The aar generated from `libA` is now used in my app project. But I can't access the classes from libExtension without using it as a separate dependency to the app project.
I'm not sure if I understood the documentation correctly but I don't think this is the correct behaviour?

Comment: you cannot use aar library files, if you want to use those classes you have to add a separate dependency to app project.

Comment: So api or implementation is just relevant for project dependencies?

Comment: AFAIK yes it is, I also faced a situation like this and wasn't able to access classes from aar file, then instead I converted that project to an android library and then implemented according to my requirements. In that way I was able to make changes to any class or layout of that specific library.

Comment: I believe aar does not contain any information about the libraries it uses. If you however distribute your aar through maven, then there will be pom.xml created, which contains list of all required libs. I believe the solution would be to use maven repository for distribution and not aar files.